# Get all values from shifting sets

Tags: algorithm

I'm downloading a twitter feed for new posts, judging by unique Post IDs. Items can be deleted or added to the feed while I'm scraping though. So by the time I get to page 2, page 1 may have changed.

I'll try to describe the process with an illustrative example,

1. Page 1's PIDs: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
2. Page 2's PIDs: 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
3. I download page 1 and all PIDs are new, so I download page 2. But an item was deleted from page one, a microsecond after I downloaded it.
4. So page 2's PIDs are now: 7, 8, 9, 10, 11

The PIDs I end up with are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11

I'm missing PID 6 and PID 1 is the newest so I won't ever find PID 6.

What algorithm can I use to ensure I get all the available PIDs?

Comment: Can we assume that PIDs are always continuous numbers without gaps?

Comment: Sorry, if I was actually using Twitter this wouldn't be a problem because they support page requests with PID offsets. I'm using another service's API which only works with index.

Comment: I've thought about guessing how many pages I'll need and grabbing all of them at once, then checking the age of the end values. That is kind of wasteful though.

Comment: @MichałKomorowski I mean, they always get larger, but by random increments.

Comment: You need to give more details about the API. From what you explained above there's no way to guarantee that you'll get all the results you want.

Comment: @sorin Ok. I did just find undocumented parameters `max_id` and `since_id` that solve this. Found them from a search for "offset" in the discussion group.